# Get records based on index

Tags: mysql

I have a table with `id (auto increment)` and `name` columns

I want a result with  8(id) to 15(id) records

I tried running the query

`"select id , name from table limit 8,15";`

but this query returns me 8th to (8+15) records.

I am expecting a query to retrieve 8th to 15th

> Example 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15(ids)

Solutions and suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change your sql from "select id , name from table limit 8,15" to select id , name from table where id between 8 and 15

Comment: Have you done any research yourself yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT id,name FROM table WHERE id>=8 AND id<=15;
```

You can also use

```
SELECT id,name FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 8 AND 15
```